# how to concatenate numeric string

Tags: string, integer, int, python-3.7

```
       ... # etc               
       MemberID = df2['Guest Number'][row_numberd2]
       MemberI = int(MemberID) # tried converting it to int
       print (MemberI)

       with open("./pdfs/" + MemberI + "%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
             output.write(outputStream)  
           # etc, yes, have tried using MemberI and MemberID above, both wont concatenate
```

The above outputs the below error; when it's a string. When I convert to int, it says it needs to be string in order to concatenate. Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.int64") to str # error using MemberID


TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str # Error using MemberI
```

Comment: You converted to integer but used the original, any way that won't help either.

Comment: @Austin yes, I have tried both variables.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
MemberID = df2['Guest Number'].astype(str).iloc[row_numberd2]
with open("./pdfs/" + MemberID + "%s.pdf" % i, "wb") as outputStream:
             output.write(outputStream)
```